# Discord.js Slash (sub)Command that (wants to) use function - ReferenceError: subcommand is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to use subcommands in a slash command for a discord bot.
There are going to be many subcommands, each one of them is similar to the other, so I was thinking to use a function that is called within .addSubCommand, but apparently it doesn't really work.

This is the code:

```
async function subCommandDB(subcommand,nameDB,name) {
    subcommand = Object();
    subcommand.setName(name)
    .setDescription('Add record to specified database')

    for (i=0;i<nameDB.properties.length;i++) {
        subcommand.addStringOption(option=>
            option.setName(nameDB.properties[i])
            .setDescription('///')
            .setRequired(true))
    }

    return subcommand
}

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('dbad')
        .setDescription('ADMIN ONLY. Add a record to the database of choice')
        .addSubcommand(subCommandDB(subcommand,dbs.itemDB,'item')),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // whatever . . .
    },
```

And this is the error:

```
C:\users\me\Documents\Discord Bot\commands\dbad.js:24
                .addSubcommand(subCommandDB(subcommand,dbs.itemDB,'item')),
                                            ^

ReferenceError: subcommand is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Documents\Discord Bot\commands\dbad.js:24:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Documents\Discord Bot\deploy-commands.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
```

If I put this within .addSubcommand(), the whole thing works:

```
    .addSubcommand(subcommand => {
            subcommand.setName('item')
            .setDescription('Add record to Item database')

            for (i=0;i<dbs.itemDB.properties.length;i++) {
                subcommand.addStringOption(option=>
                    option.setName(dbs.itemDB.properties[i])
                    .setDescription('a')
                    .setRequired(true))
            }

            return subcommand
        }),
```

And this chunk of code is what I hope to transform into that function.
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It should be `.addSubcommand(subcommand => subCommandDB(subcommand, ...`

Comment: We don't so "SOLVED" in the title here. If you found your answer you can post it and accept it, or delete the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works:

```
function subCommandDB(subcommand,nameDB,name) {
    subcommand.setName(name)
    .setDescription('Add record to specified database')

    for (i=0;i<nameDB.properties.length;i++) {
        subcommand.addStringOption(option=>
            option.setName(nameDB.properties[i])
            .setDescription('///')
            .setRequired(true))
    }

    return subcommand
}

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('dbad')
        .setDescription('ADMIN ONLY. Add a record to the database of choice')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand => subCommandDB(subcommand,dbs.itemDB,'item')),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // whatever . . .
    },
```

Main issue was that async function returned a promise, whereas the .addSubcommand(...) requires a [Function: SlashCommandSubcommandBuilder] - which means that a regular function is required instead of the async one